# Xamarin Forms: CPU and RAM usage programmatically

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get CPU usage and RAM of my application, I come here because I can't do it...
Everytime I got a weird value.

I tried this (from Xamarin forum), but I need to use StopWatch everytime and it doesn't looks like my CPU usage:

```
var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
Console.WriteLine("STATS|CPU={Cpu}%|Mem={Mem}", (int)(100 * proc.TotalProcessorTime.TotalMilliseconds / beginSW.ElapsedMilliseconds), proc.WorkingSet64);
```

Tried to use PerformanceCounter but it not works...

Anyone have a solution to get CPU usage & RAM?

Thank you!

EDIT: I made something like this, but it's not really accurate because I compare scaled cpu and info cpu...

```
public string GetProcess()
{
    var result = "";
    var index = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            index = i;
            var readerCurFreq = new RandomAccessFile($"/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu{i}/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq", "r");
            var readerMaxFreq = new RandomAccessFile($"/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu{i}/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq", "r");
            var curfreg = readerCurFreq.ReadLine();
            var maxfreg = readerMaxFreq.ReadLine();

            var currentFreq = double.Parse(curfreg) / 1000;
            var maxFreq = double.Parse(maxfreg) / 1000;

            readerCurFreq.Close();
            readerMaxFreq.Close();

            var cpu = currentFreq * 100 / maxFreq;

            result += $"CPU{i}: {cpu}%\n";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result += $"CPU{index}: NO VALUES\n";
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: It would be better to use tools, two profiler tools are available to serve this purpose:
Xamarin Profiler, Android Profiler in Android Studio. Please check the MS docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/profiling

Comment: No I want to get it programmatically because I want to makes logs with it ^^

Comment: For memory, try [GC.GetTotalMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.gettotalmemory?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_GC_GetTotalMemory_System_Boolean_)

Comment: Yup, RAM is ok, but cpu usage... I can get frequency per core, but not in percentage... with "scaling_cur_freq" in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/user-guide.txt

Comment: I edited my original post with code

Comment: You could try the code in the link below to get the CPU usage with `RandomAccessFile`. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/155630/how-to-calculate-cpu-usage-from-reading-proc-stat-file